# How do you get Visual Studio to respect breakpoints set in a razor page?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a razor page called manager.cshtml that contains a `List` that's used to generate navigation tabs. I've set a breakpoint so I can inspect the `List` but Visual Studio is not stopping at the break point.

```
@{
var tabs = pageTabs.ToList();
}

@if (tabs.Count > 0) //breakpoint set here
```

I'm in Debug mode. Is there another setting I need to enable?

Comment: Does the breakpoint just not work in the view, what about server side?

Comment: It works in code behind files just fine.